# Enemies Not Unpausing In Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, self

The sprites in the  `Enemy` group move in random directions. If they hit the window's edge, they bounce back(left to right, right to left). When `P` is pressed, `.stop()` causes all the enemies to pause. `.start()` unpauses it. However, now the enemies fly off-screen pass the boundaries set to the left and right of the window. `.start()` should have kept didn't change anything set in `.update()`.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy-spaceship-sprite.png")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale( self.image, (50, 50))
        self.image.set_colorkey( self.image.get_at( (1,1) ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        self.rect.center = position
        (self.speedX, self.speedY) = speed
        self.speedHolder = speed

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (self.rect.centerx + self.speedX, self.rect.centery + self.speedY)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.speedX = abs(self.speedX)
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH :
            self.speedX = -1 * abs(self.speedX)
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.speedY = abs(self.speedY)
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = 0

    def stop(self):
        self.speedY = 0
        self.speedX = 0
    def start(self):
        (self.speedX, self.speedY) = self.speedHolder
```

Game Loop:

```
keepGoing = True
while keepGoing:
    # Set FPS of the game - 30 frames per second/tick
    clock.tick(CLOCK_TICK)
    # Every 30 ticks is a second
    tickCount += 1

    # Pause everything in the game
    if pause == True:
        for eachEnemy in enemyGroup:
            eachEnemy.stop()
    else:
        for eachEnemy in enemyGroup:
            eachEnemy.start()

########### Bunch of skipped code ###########
        missileGroup.clear(screen, background)
        missileGroup.update()
        missileGroup.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: What does `self.speedHolder` hold?

Comment: Where do you set and change `pause`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate It holds the `speed` argument because after `Enemy` is stopped, their old directions were erased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using a list for the initial enemy `speed` parameter, rather than a tuple.

The difference is important, because a Python list will be passed as a *reference*, and a tuple passed as a *value*.  So when the speed is passed as a list, the initialiser `self.speedHolder = speed` does not make a copy of the values, it just keeps pointing to the original list.  Probably all your instances of an `Enemy` use the same list.

If this list is changed, the value pointed to in `Enemy.start()` obviously changes too.  So you would see the described behaviour.

Ensure that when you create an instance of an `Enemy`, that `speed` is a tuple, e.g.:

```
position = ( 100, 100 )
speed    = ( 3, 3 )                       # speed is a tuple
monster  = new Enemy( position, speed )   # <<-- tuples pass by value (copy)
speed    = ( 20, -3 )                     # nothing happens to monster
```

and NOT:

```
position = [ 100, 100 ]
speed    = [ 3, 3 ]                       # speed is a list
monster  = new Enemy( position, speed )   # <<-- lists passed by reference
speed    = [ 20, -3 ]                     # monster now moves erratically
```